# how can I get other db instance in nodejs 3.0 mongo-client?

Tags: mongodb

I used mongo-nodejs 2.2 and upgraded to 3.0. After upgrading, I found that the method `db()` in Db class doesn't exist anymore (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Db.html). This method is very useful to switch to different database instance. I wonder how I can switch to different database with the latest version.

Comment: *"  I found that the method db() in Db class doesn't exist anymore "* are you **certain** of that, or is it just an oversight in the documentation? There is `admin()`, which is essentially just a `db()` with the value already set. And there is `db()` from the `MongoClient` interface, and the one change in the connection method means you "should" have that reference available to you since it's returned by the connection. In reality i think you "should" be using the client interface method now, but I kind of have a feeling the method is actually still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it is gone, and it's documented as gone and the real message is you should be using `Mongoclient.prototype.db` instead:

From the [3.0 Changes](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#api-changes):

> We removed the following API methods.
>
> - Db.prototype.authenticate
> - Db.prototype.logout
> - Db.prototype.open
> - **Db.prototype.db**
>
> ...
>
> We've added the following API methods.
>
> - MongoClient.prototype.logout
> - MongoClient.prototype.isConnected
> - **MongoClient.prototype.db**

The basic lesson here was wherever you were using `Db` directly, you should be using the `MongoClient` instance instead. This is obtained from the very first connection:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

(async function() {
  try {
    const conn = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost');

    let test = conn.db('test');
    let admin = test.admin();

    console.log(admin);

    let another = conn.db('another');

    console.log(another);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }
})()
```

Returns output like:

```
Admin {
  s:
   { db:
      Db {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter] },
     topology:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 25,
        _maxListeners: Infinity,
        clientInfo: [Object],
        s: [Object] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] } }
Db {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s:
   { databaseName: 'another',
     dbCache: {},
     children: [],
     topology:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 25,
        _maxListeners: Infinity,
        clientInfo: [Object],
        s: [Object] },
     options:
      { readPreference: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] },
     logger: Logger { className: 'Db' },
     bson: BSON {},
     readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: undefined },
     bufferMaxEntries: -1,
     parentDb: null,
     pkFactory: undefined,
     nativeParser: undefined,
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     noListener: false,
     readConcern: undefined },
  serverConfig: [Getter],
  bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
  databaseName: [Getter] }
```

Interestingly the `admin()` helper still exists on `Db` instances, which of course is really just a "pre filled" selection to the old `db()` anyway.

Bottom line, use the `MongoClient` instance from the connection instead for all future code.